# KIF 3.2.0 failing for arm64 configuration

Tags: ios, kif

I am trying to use KIF v3.2(latest as of 03/18/2015). It is complaining about undefined symbols for arm64 for UIEvent+KIFAdditions.o

Error:
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_IOHIDEventCreateDigitizerEvent", referenced from:
      -[UIEvent(KIFAdditions) kif_setIOHIDEventWithTouches:] in UIEvent+KIFAdditions.o
      -[UIEvent(KIFAdditions) kif_setIOHIDEventWithTouches:] in libKIF.a(UIEvent+KIFAdditions.o)
  "_IOHIDEventCreateDigitizerFingerEventWithQuality", referenced from:
      -[UIEvent(KIFAdditions) kif_setIOHIDEventWithTouches:] in UIEvent+KIFAdditions.o
      -[UIEvent(KIFAdditions) kif_setIOHIDEventWithTouches:] in libKIF.a(UIEvent+KIFAdditions.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SenTestCase", referenced from:
      l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_SenTestCase_$_KIFAdditions in SenTestCase-KIFAdditions.o
  "_IOHIDEventAppendEvent", referenced from:
      -[UIEvent(KIFAdditions) kif_setIOHIDEventWithTouches:] in UIEvent+KIFAdditions.o
      -[UIEvent(KIFAdditions) kif_setIOHIDEventWithTouches:] in libKIF.a(UIEvent+KIFAdditions.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Does anyone know whats going on here. Seems only that file has problem building for arm64. Please let me know if anyone has success building KIF v3.2.0 in their project. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It was happening because of missing IOKit.framework.

Comment: Can you please give more info on how you resolved this?

Comment: Basically, I had created KIF static library using both arm and i386 architectures. Now while using that library in my main project I was missing IOKit.framework and hence it was failing to find those symbols. Once I have added that my project built fine.

Comment: The steps documented here helped me to fix this issue: https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF/issues/602 .  Xcode (6.3) added some header search paths to my project that had to be removed before the project would build.